# Troubles with BST recursion (finding height of a tree in C++)

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

```
int BST::getLength()
{
    int leftHeight = 0;
    int rightHeight = 0;

    // Empty case
    if (!prev && !dataInit)
        return 0;


    else
    {
        if (left)
        {
            leftHeight = left->getLength();

            std::cout << "leftHeight: " << leftHeight;
            std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
        }
        if (right)
        {
            rightHeight = right->getLength();

            std::cout << "rightHeight: " << rightHeight;
            std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
        }

        if (leftHeight > rightHeight)
            return leftHeight + 1;
        else
            return rightHeight + 1;
    }
}
```

This is a copied function from some website. I've been trying to write this function down on paper to understand the recursion but I can't seem to find myself comprehending. Specifically, I don't understand how leftHeight and rightHeight are incrementing by one if we're recursively calling it before we add 1.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Please edit your post with the definitions of `left` and `right`, in text (not images).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not completely sure about the structure of the rest of this code but I will hazard a guess here. It helps if we start thinking of base cases. For a binary tree, that would be the leaf nodes. For a leaf node, the height of its left or right children would be zero and the height of the entire tree including the leaf node is one.

We can then take a step back and consider a general node in the binary tree: the height of the tree starting at this node is `max(leftSubTree, rightSubTree) + 1`, where the +1 accounts for the current node.

Comment: How would 'leftSubTree' and 'rightSubTree' be traversing/incrementing in between calls then. Because we aren't going to the end of a tree then traversing back. Also, how does this code and concept avoid a 'dead end' of sorts where perhaps we reach ends of the tree which are not the tallest.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by traversing to the end and going back? `leftSubTree` and `rightSubTree` would just be pointers to the left and right subtrees in this made up example. We avoid the dead end by returning the bigger number at each node i.e. in the last 4 lines of the code.

Regardless, answering this completely requires a bit more information about how this particular tree is represented. In particular what do the `prev` and `dataInit` variables mean since they are being used in the base case here. I guess my answer would have been better off as a comment instead.

Comment: Treat dataInit as the data in the node class (BST). prev is a pointer to the parent node. This is just to cover if there are no nodes within the BST; I want to be able to make it empty

Comment: Each node recursively gets the height of its left subtree and its right subtree, takes the larger of the two and adds one (to count itself) and returns that value to the caller.  The recursion is asking its children what their height is, which is done the same way, by asking _their_ children their height, and adding one, and returning that.  It keeps going farther down the tree, and adding 1 as it returns, accumulating the height as the recursive function calls return their value.  The parent nodes keeps adding 1 to the max of its children, until the top tree root returns the total height.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. Quite a beautiful algorithm for such a simple operation